# Matplotlib scatter - imshow offset

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter, imshow

I am overlaying a scatter plot of points on an imshow 128 x 128 pixels. If you look closely here: [image: this]

the objects do not always fall exactly on the center of the corresponding pixels. I tried different interpolations on imshow and origins for scatter, but nothing changed. So I thought I could overlay a grid to see how much this offset actually is:
[image: no_grid]

and I noticed that the grid also falls exactly on the objects and not the center of the imshow pixels. The script for the above plot is:

```
   fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
   plt.imshow(counts_pre[:,:,slice_z],cmap='viridis',interpolation=None)
   plt.scatter(j_index,i_index, s = 0.1, c = 'red', marker = 'o')

   myInterval=1.
   loc = matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(base=myInterval)
   plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)
   plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_locator(loc)

   plt.grid(which="both", linewidth=0.72,color="white",alpha=0.1)
   plt.tick_params(which="minor", length=0)

   plt.show()
```

Any ideas on why this offset exists and how I can fix it? Notice that the grid is not very homogeneous, i.e. some squares are rectangular.

Edit:

1. Upgrading to the newest matplotlib version did not resolve the
   issue.
2. I created objects where the entries are non-zero, such that I know that the points should be perfectly aligned, but they still don't match up.

Comment: Are you running the latest matplotlib version? The current default seems to be that the x-range goes from `-0.5` to `x_size+0.5`, having the integer positions nicely in the center of the cells.

Comment: I am running 3.1.2, I see the latest release is 3.3.1, will upgrade and check if the issue is fixed!

Comment: The issue did not go away. I noticed that the lower the resolution the less intense the problem is, so I don't know if such a test could help. However, the scripts are pretty fast anyway.

Comment: The 10x10 is not meant for speed, but to better observe what happens. If you only have a problem with higher resolutions, this looks like an aliasing problem.  You can only tackle it when you save the plot as an image, with `dpi=...`